# Get All Anchor Tags

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

Good day!

My regular expression is really bad and I would like to ask for help on my project.

I have contents that I crawled from other sites and I would like to get all anchor tags that have this string in them.

```
target="_blank"
```

How will I accomplish this? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Don't try to use regular expressions on arbitrary HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454), you can get away with it on HTML that fits a specific template, but it isn't safe for "contents you've crawled from other sites".

Comment: I have an HTML that fits a specific template. Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($yourCobtent);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$yourAnchors = $xpath->query('//a[@target="_blank"]');
```

Comment: Might want to assign the return value of `DOMXPath::query()` to something there

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, regular expressions are not the answer here.

Use DOM and XPath to achieve what you want

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.example.com/some-file.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query('//a[@target="_blank"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with @quentin, however you can use regexr, [(http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), a basic regex for all anchor tags is `<a.*href=["'](?<url>[^"]+[.\s]*)["'].*>(?<name>[^<]+[.\s]*)</a>`
[(http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2004/06/18/regex-pattern-for-anchor-tags-part-2.aspx)](http://weblogs.asp.net/palermo4/archive/2004/06/18/regex-pattern-for-anchor-tags-part-2.aspx)